# Python: How to get an array into an SQL Database

Tags: python, arrays, database, sqlite

I hope you can help me with this one:
I want to save an array like this in a the Python Sqlite3 database.

```
test = {
    'Peter': {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'E': 1},
    'Jack': {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}
}
```

What would be a good solution to this?

Comment: The array you're showing is not valid in python syntax. Perhaps you mean `Peter:{}`? You're missing a colon there.

Comment: So, now, you've fixed it. Do you mean you want to store it in table `Peter` and `Jack`?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [standard Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for SQLite. Your data can be mapped to rows with the key of every entry being the ID in the DB table.

```
import sqlite3

d  = {
  'Peter': {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'E': 1},
  'Jack': {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}
}

con = sqlite3.connect("/tmp/d.sqlite3")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("create table t (id text, a integer, b integer, c integer, d integer, e integer)")
cur.executemany("insert into t values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
  [(k, v.get('A', None), v.get('B', None), v.get('C', None), v.get('D', None), v.get('E', None)) for k, v in d.items()])
con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from t")
cur.fetchall()

# [('Peter', 1, 1, 1, None, 1),
#  ('Jack', 1, 1, None, 1, 1)]
```